# start microsoft edge in fullscreen

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I am repairing a few computers for use as digital signs. I therefore want a script to start Microsoft Edge in fullscreen on boot. The website I set as default in the settings but I have no clue on how to start the app in fullscreen, any ideas?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1090711/start-microsoft-edge-maximized-on-first-run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty popular post for Google Searches, so I figured I would add my solution to this question. Windows 10 1809+ includes a new Kiosk mode, where an administrator can specify a user account to run, an application to run, and a website to run. This is great for digital displays that turn off and on at specified times.

The full instructions are here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app

The current instructions are as follows. Note there are PowerShell scripts at the link above that can do this as well.

---

To set up assigned access in PC settings

- Go to Start > Settings > Accounts > Other users.
- Select Set up a kiosk > Assigned access, and then select Get started.
- Enter a name for the new account.

  - Note: If there are any local standard user accounts on the device already, the Create an account page will offer the option to Choose an existing account.
- Choose the app that will run when the kiosk account signs in. Only apps that can run above the lock screen will be available in the list of apps to choose from. For more information, see Guidelines for choosing an app for assigned access. If you select Microsoft Edge as the kiosk app, you configure the following options:

  - Whether Microsoft Edge should display your website full-screen (digital sign) or with some browser controls available (public browser)
  - Which URL should be displayed when the kiosk accounts signs in
  - When Microsoft Edge should restart after a period of inactivity (if you select to run as a public browser)
- Select Close.

---

To remove assigned access, select the account tile on the Set up a kiosk page, and then select Remove kiosk.

Answer (score 8):

By changing the script posted on https://superuser.com/questions/1090711/start-microsoft-edge-maximized-on-first-run a little I was able to fullscreen the microsoft edge app on launch.

```
start microsoft-edge:http://google.com
>> $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
>> $wshell.AppActivate('Google - Microsoft Edge')
>> Sleep 2
>> $wshell.SendKeys('{F11}')
```

Thanks to [How to send CTRL or ALT + any other key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824799/how-to-send-ctrl-or-alt-any-other-key) I found the proper key for F11 and got the script working.

Answer (score 6):

Powershell script sample:

```
start microsoft-edge:https://netflix.com/browse

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;

$wshell.AppActivate('edge') 

while ($true)
{
    Sleep 2
    $wshell.SendKeys('{f11}')
    exit 
}

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not work anymore. The issue is the Sendkeys command. It is not supported in universal apps on windows 10. According to this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/always-on-full-screen-mode-in-ms-edge/0650c85e-fe80-451d-a65a-ea2687dd02e1 it is not possible to start edge in full screen mode unless via a GPO.

Answer (score 0):

The script above does work, but you have to follow a short process first,

Place the script in the startup folder, (use file explorere and type shell:startup in the address bar).

Manually Run the script, when edge opens in minimised mode, maximise it.

then close edge and run the script again, this time it will open in maximised mode.

Reboot and watch the magic work.

Answer (score 0):

```
`<sus.xbox.edge+!>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:com="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/com/windows10" xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" xmlns:uap10="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/10" xmlns:uap2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/2" xmlns:uap3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3" xmlns:uap4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/4" xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5" xmlns:uap6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/6" IgnorableNamespaces="uap10">
  <Identity Name="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge.Stable" ProcessorArchitecture="x64" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" Version="117.0.2045.34" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>Microsoft Edge</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Microsoft Corporation</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Description>Reserved</Description>
    <Logo>VisualElements\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="en-us" />
  </Resources>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily MaxVersionTested="12.0.0.0" MinVersion="10.0.17701.0" Name="Windows.Core" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily MaxVersionTested="12.0.0.0" MinVersion="10.0.17701.0" Name="Windows.Holographic" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily MaxVersionTested="12.0.0.0" MinVersion="10.0.17701.0" Name="Windows.Xbox" />
    <PackageDependency MinVersion="14.0.25426.0" Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="packageManagement" />
    <uap4:CustomCapability Name="Microsoft.deployFullTrustOnHost_8wekyb3d8bbwe" />
  </Capabilities>
  <Applications>
    <Application EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication" Executable="msedge.exe" Id="MSEDGE" uap10:RuntimeBehavior="packagedClassicApp" uap10:TrustLevel="mediumIL">
      <uap:VisualElements BackgroundColor="transparent" Description="Microsoft Edge" DisplayName="Microsoft Edge" Square150x150Logo="VisualElements\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="VisualElements\Square44x44Logo.png">
        <uap:DefaultTile Square310x310Logo="VisualElements\Square310x310Logo.png" Square71x71Logo="VisualElements\Square71x71Logo.png" Wide310x150Logo="VisualElements\Wide310x150Logo.png">
          <uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="square150x150Logo" />
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="wide310x150Logo" />
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="square310x310Logo" />
          </uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
        </uap:DefaultTile>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="VisualElements\Wide310x150Logo.scale-400.png" />      </uap:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        
        
        <Extension Category="windows.preInstalledConfigTask" EntryPoint="background_updater_wcos.PreInstallConfigTask" /><com:Extension Category="windows.comServer">
          <com:ComServer>
            <com:ExeServer Executable="notification_helper.exe">
              <com:Class Id="628ACE20-B77A-456F-A88D-547DB6CEEDD5" />
            </com:ExeServer>
          </com:ComServer>
        </com:Extension>
        <com:Extension Category="windows.comServer">
          <com:ComServer>
            <com:ExeServer Executable="background_updater.exe" LaunchAndActivationPermission="O:SYG:SYD:(A;;11;;;IU)(A;;11;;;S-1-15-2-543634040-274359014-2226501544-3561766748-3991453649-3543631192-522786984)S:P(ML;;NX;;;ME)">
              <com:Class Id="508E276B-96B3-46B4-A254-833BE08DB03B" />
            </com:ExeServer>
          </com:ComServer>
        </com:Extension>
        
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap3:FileTypeAssociation Name="htm">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.htm</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
            <uap2:SupportedVerbs>
              <uap3:Verb Id="open" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">open</uap3:Verb>
            </uap2:SupportedVerbs>
          </uap3:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap3:FileTypeAssociation Name="html">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.html</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
            <uap2:SupportedVerbs>
              <uap3:Verb Id="open" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">open</uap3:Verb>
            </uap2:SupportedVerbs>
          </uap3:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap3:FileTypeAssociation Name="pdf">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.pdf</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\pdf.png</uap:Logo>
            <uap2:SupportedVerbs>
              <uap3:Verb Id="open" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">open</uap3:Verb>
            </uap2:SupportedVerbs>
          </uap3:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap3:FileTypeAssociation Name="shtml">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.shtml</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
            <uap2:SupportedVerbs>
              <uap3:Verb Id="open" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">open</uap3:Verb>
            </uap2:SupportedVerbs>
          </uap3:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap3:FileTypeAssociation Name="svg">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.svg</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
            <uap2:SupportedVerbs>
              <uap3:Verb Id="open" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">open</uap3:Verb>
            </uap2:SupportedVerbs>
          </uap3:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap3:FileTypeAssociation Name="webp">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.webp</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
            <uap2:SupportedVerbs>
              <uap3:Verb Id="open" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">open</uap3:Verb>
            </uap2:SupportedVerbs>
          </uap3:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap3:FileTypeAssociation Name="xht">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.xht</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
            <uap2:SupportedVerbs>
              <uap3:Verb Id="open" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">open</uap3:Verb>
            </uap2:SupportedVerbs>
          </uap3:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap3:FileTypeAssociation Name="xhtml">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.xhtml</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
            <uap2:SupportedVerbs>
              <uap3:Verb Id="open" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">open</uap3:Verb>
            </uap2:SupportedVerbs>
          </uap3:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap3:Extension>
        
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap3:Protocol Name="ftp" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">
            <uap:DisplayName>ftp</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
          </uap3:Protocol>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap3:Protocol Name="http" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">
            <uap:DisplayName>http</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
          </uap3:Protocol>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap3:Protocol Name="https" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">
            <uap:DisplayName>https</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
          </uap3:Protocol>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap3:Protocol Name="irc" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">
            <uap:DisplayName>irc</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
          </uap3:Protocol>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap3:Protocol Name="mailto" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">
            <uap:DisplayName>mailto</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
          </uap3:Protocol>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap3:Protocol Name="microsoft-edge" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">
            <uap:DisplayName>microsoft-edge</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
          </uap3:Protocol>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap3:Protocol Name="mms" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">
            <uap:DisplayName>mms</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
          </uap3:Protocol>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap3:Protocol Name="news" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">
            <uap:DisplayName>news</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
          </uap3:Protocol>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap3:Protocol Name="nntp" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">
            <uap:DisplayName>nntp</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
          </uap3:Protocol>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap3:Protocol Name="sms" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">
            <uap:DisplayName>sms</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
          </uap3:Protocol>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap3:Protocol Name="smsto" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">
            <uap:DisplayName>smsto</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
          </uap3:Protocol>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap3:Protocol Name="tel" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">
            <uap:DisplayName>tel</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
          </uap3:Protocol>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap3:Protocol Name="urn" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">
            <uap:DisplayName>urn</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
          </uap3:Protocol>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap3:Protocol Name="webcal" Parameters="-- &quot;%1&quot;">
            <uap:DisplayName>webcal</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:Logo>VisualElements\htm.png</uap:Logo>
          </uap3:Protocol>
        </uap3:Extension>
        <uap5:Extension Category="windows.appExecutionAlias" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication" Executable="msedge.exe">
          <uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
            <uap5:ExecutionAlias Alias="EdgeStable.exe" />
          </uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
        </uap5:Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Extensions>
    <uap10:Extension Category="windows.hostRuntime" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication" Executable="pwahelper.exe" uap10:RuntimeBehavior="packagedClassicApp" uap10:TrustLevel="mediumIL">
      <uap10:HostRuntime Id="PWA" />
    </uap10:Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>background_updater_winrt.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="background_updater_wcos.PreInstallConfigTask" ThreadingModel="MTA" />
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
    <uap6:Extension Category="windows.loaderSearchPathOverride">
      <uap6:LoaderSearchPathOverride>
        <uap6:LoaderSearchPathEntry FolderPath="" />
      </uap6:LoaderSearchPathOverride>
    </uap6:Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.publisherCacheFolders">
      <PublisherCacheFolders>
        <Folder Name="DefaultChannel" />
      </PublisherCacheFolders>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
</Package>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).