# How to open Edge using Powershell variable?

Tags: windows, powershell, microsoft-edge

I have tried the following:

```
$edge = New-Object -com microsoft-edge.application
$edge.visible = $true
$edge.FullScreen = $true
```

But I get error:

```
New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed
due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from 
HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
At line:1 char:9
+ $edge = New-Object -com microsoft-edge.application
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Edit 17/07/2019 - I have changed to below:

```
$edge = Start-Process -FilePath ($Env:WinDir + "\explorer.exe") 
-ArgumentList 
"shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge"
$edge.visible = $true
$edge.FullScreen = $true
```

So now Edge opens but the Visible and Fullscreen commands return errors - anyone have any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: has edge been run at least once by that account on that system?

Comment: Edge is not automatable in that way - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302304/will-microsoft-edge-support-com-automation-internetexplorer-object

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey Yes it has been run before

Comment: @Naz - isee that `TessellatingHeckler` has the answer ... you can't do that in that manner. [*grin*]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this might be the solution:

```
start microsoft-edge:http://google.com
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Google - Microsoft Edge')
Sleep 2
$wshell.SendKeys('{F11}')
```

I found the above code here:[start microsoft edge in fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617117/start-microsoft-edge-in-fullscreen)

You can send edge different keys depending on what you want:
[How to send CTRL or ALT + any other key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824799/how-to-send-ctrl-or-alt-any-other-key)

You could find the key shortcut to whatever you want to do to the Edge window.

You could try this(source is link below):

```
Start-Process -FilePath ($Env:WinDir + "\explorer.exe") -ArgumentList "shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge"
```

There is also a way to open it in Incognito Mode:

[How to start Microsoft Edge in private mode by PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-start-Edge-in-bfff2c34)

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried it and it works to open it. However, the Fullscreen and Visible commands still return errors - any ideas?

Comment: Actually, while looking this up, since I had no idea, I found a better solution. I'll add it to my answer

Comment: For me, the Sleep command before issuing seemed to help.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the following command to open Microsoft Edge browser and navigate to the special URL.

```
start microsoft-edge:http://google.com
```

Edit:

If you want to use Edge Webdriver to open IE browser, you could download the Edge webdriver from [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/), and refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver) to use it.

Answer (score 3):

> The existing answers may work for some environments, **BUT** they are not guaranteed since they use the alias `start` instead of the `Start-Process` command directly.

[It is best to use the command directly in scripts.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/when-you-should-use-powershell-aliases/)

---

**Open Edge full screen:**

```
Start-Process microsoft-edge: -WindowStyle maximized
```

**Explanation**

The `Start-Process` command is executed on microsoft-edge, with the argument `-WindowStyle` set to maximized. This will open edge and maximize it to full screen.

---

**Open Edge full screen AND navigate to specified webpage:**

```
Start-Process microsoft-edge:https://stackoverflow.com -WindowStyle maximized
```

**Explanation**

Like before, the `Start-Process` command is executed on microsoft-edge and the `:` specifies to open https://stackoverflow.com. The argument `-WindowStyle` set to maximized will full screen Edge and load stackoverflow.com.

---

[Official documentation: Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)

Comment: How can I control whether the tab opens in a new window or not? When I leave the URL blank it opens in a new window `Start-Process microsoft-edge: -WindowStyle maximized` , but when I add a URL (like this answer) it opens in a previous window. I want to force it to open in a new window.

Comment: Update on previous comment, leaving the URL blank (`:` followed by nothing) the script errors out with a `NullArgumentException`... which suggests the opening in a new window is an accident. How can I intentionally do this then?

Comment: How to open an extension page using Start-Process script? I tried using extension:// and chrome-extension:// but neither worked. Basically, I want to open non-http urls from powershell script inside edge browser.