# The start-process cmdlet of powershell will fail with -PassThru argument when trying to launch Edge browser

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge

In my test script by powershell, I'd start an Edge browser and get it's main process's ID. Simply like this:

```
$edge = Start-Process microsoft-edge: www.ted.com -PassThru
```

but instead of able to get the process id from $edge.Id, I've got error message like this:

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run completely because the system cannot find all the information required.
At line:1 char:7
+ $edge=Start-Process microsoft-edge: www.ted.com -PassThru
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Is there any simple and straightforward way to really doing this without enumerate and check the process list?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053312/how-to-open-edge-using-powershell-variable

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but that didn't resolved my problem. In my case, the edge browser does started, only that the process object is not granted for been referenced by the variable. Using explorer.exe or cmd.exe would not give the error message, but you'll get the process id for the launcher instead of the browser been launched. Any other idea is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I try to test your script and I am getting a similar error as yours.

Based on my search result, **passthru** is not one of the common parameters, and it does not exist everywhere.

Reference:

[Use the PowerShell Passthru Parameter and Get Back Objects](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-the-powershell-passthru-parameter-and-get-back-objects/)

I think it is not available for the MS Edge browser and that's why the script gives an error.

I try to search for an alternative command for **PassThru** but I did not get any helpful information about it.

In this situation, it is better to enumerate and check the process list

Comment: Ha, thanks for your reply and looking into this. I've noticed that the problem seems to be with the metro apps. I've tried the command with the calculator:
Start-Process calculator: -PassThru 
and got the same kind of outcome. 
So, you work for MSFT? Looking forward for Microsoft to have this kind of problem fixed then. Regards,

Comment: MS Edge browser is the UWP app that do not launch like other .EXE file and as I informed you PassThru is not available for all the applications. So this can be the reason that it is not working.

Comment: tks, that passtru doesn't exist for Windows Explorer too, when start-proces a folder path